# Basic Bash Function to find and copy files based on filetype

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use the little bit of code below to find files in a folder with a given filetype and then copy them to a different folder.

```
find ./ -name '*.chk' -exec cp -prv '{}' "./" ';'
```

I tried to change this into a function in my .bash_profile so I could use it more quickly, but for some reason, it's not working.  By not working, I mean nothing seems to happen when I execute "mymove .txt folder".  Bash just goes to a new line, ready to accept more input.

```
mymove() {
        find ./ -name "$1" -exec cp -prv '{}' "$2" ';';
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks.  I've added clarification.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just searching?

Comment: You should use mymove like so: `mymove '*.chk' foo/`.

Comment: The reason is, you need to pass that pattern `*.chk` to `find`, NOT have the current shell expand it first. The single quotes protect it from expansion by the current shell, and thus `find` is handed that unexpanded pattern `*.chk`.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you execute `mymove` with two parameters, `.txt` and `folder`:

```
$ mymove .txt folder
```

This will not work as `.txt` doesn't match any files, change it to:

```
$ mymove '*.txt' folder
```

Note the quotes, you do *not* want to shell to expand `*.txt`.